# problema hibernate Envers "ID" Invaled Identifier

Tags: java, hibernate

Buenas a todos mi problema es el siguiente.

Tengo que hacer auditoria de las entidades de mi aplicación. Para ello hago uso de la herramienta **Hibernate Envers**.

Tengo todas las entidades que quiero persistir anotadas con **@Audited**. Ademas he añadido manualmente las tablas **_AUD** y **REVINFO** con sus respectivos campos **REV, REVTYPE y REV, REVTSTMP**. También tengo creada la sequencia **HIBERNATE_SEQUENCE** que se necesita.

Necesito añadir a la tabla **REVINFO** otras columnas para añadir informacion adicional como el usuario que hizo la transacción, la ip desde donde se hizo etc etc.

Para ello he creado la clase **RenInfo** la cual extiende de **DefaultRevisionEntity**:

```
@Entity
@RevisionEntity(RevInfoListener.class)
public class Revinfo extends DefaultRevisionEntity{

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -4464220985145031968L;

    @Column(name="USER_NAME")
    private String username;

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

     @ManyToOne(optional=false)
     @JoinColumn(name="userID",referencedColumnName="ID")
     private User auditor;

}
```

Y la clase **Listener** para poder añadir la información adicional:

```
package com.minhap.listener;

import org.hibernate.envers.RevisionListener;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;

import com.minhap.Util.AutowireHelper;
import com.minhap.model.Revinfo;
import com.minhap.security.SecurityService;

public class RevInfoListener implements RevisionListener {

    @Autowired
    private SecurityService securityService;

    @Override
    public void newRevision(Object revisionEntity) {
        Revinfo entity = (Revinfo)revisionEntity;
        AutowireHelper.autowire(this);
        entity.setUsername(securityService.getLogged().getName());

    }

    public SecurityService getSecurityService() {
        return securityService;
    }

    public void setSecurityService(SecurityService securityService) {
        this.securityService = securityService;
    }

}
```

La Clase **User**:(Que es con la que estoy haciendo pruebas)

```
package com.minhap.model;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.sql.Timestamp;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import javax.inject.Named;
import javax.persistence.*;

import org.hibernate.envers.Audited;

@Entity
@Named
@Table(name = "USERS")
@Audited
public class User implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 4092545745731449659L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "USER_SEQ")
    @SequenceGenerator(sequenceName = "USER_SEQ", allocationSize = 1, name = "USER_SEQ")
    private Long id;
    private Timestamp fx_High;
    private Timestamp fx_Modification;
    public String certificate;
    private String nif;
    private String name;
    private String password;
    private String firstname;
    private String lastname;
    private String email;
    private Long phone;
    private Long state;


    public User() {
        super();
    }
    @Transient
    private List<Privilege> privileges;

   @OneToMany(mappedBy="user" )
    private List<Solicitude> solicitude;

   @OneToMany(mappedBy="user_res" )
   private List<Solicitude> solicitude_res;

    @ManyToMany()
    @JoinTable( 
        name = "user_role",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(
          name = "users_id", referencedColumnName = "id"), 
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(
          name = "role_id", referencedColumnName = "id")) 
    private List<Role> roles  = new ArrayList<>();


    @ManyToMany()
    @JoinTable( 
        name = "manager", 
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(
          name = "users_id", referencedColumnName = "id"), 
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(
          name = "sp_id", referencedColumnName = "id")) 
    private List<Sp> sp_manager  = new ArrayList<>();

    @ManyToMany()
    @JoinTable( 
            name = "contact", 
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(
              name = "users_id", referencedColumnName = "id"), 
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(
              name = "sp_id", referencedColumnName = "id")) 
     private List<Sp> sp_contact  = new ArrayList<>();

    @ManyToMany()
    @JoinTable( 
        name = "rmanager", 
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(
          name = "users_id", referencedColumnName = "id"), 
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(
          name = "spr_id", referencedColumnName = "id")) 
    private List<SpR> spr_manager  = new ArrayList<>();

    @ManyToMany()
    @JoinTable( 
            name = "rcontact", 
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(
              name = "users_id", referencedColumnName = "id"), 
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(
              name = "spr_id", referencedColumnName = "id")) 
     private List<SpR> spr_contact  = new ArrayList<>();

    @PostLoad
    private void loadPrivileges() {
        privileges = new ArrayList<>();
        Map<Long, Privilege> mapPrivileges = new HashMap<>();

        for (Role rol : roles) {
            for (Privilege privilege : rol.getPrivileges()) {
                if (!mapPrivileges.containsKey(privilege.getId())) {
                    mapPrivileges.put(privilege.getId(), privilege);
                }
            }
        }

        privileges = new ArrayList<>(mapPrivileges.values());
    }

   @Override
   public int hashCode() {
       final int prime = 31;
       int result = 1; 
       result = (prime * result) + ((email == null) ? 0 : email.hashCode());
       return result;
   }

   @Override
   public boolean equals(final Object obj) {
       if (this == obj) {
           return true;
       }
       if (obj == null) {
           return false;
       }
       if (getClass() != obj.getClass()) {
           return false;
       }
       final User user = (User) obj;
       if (!name.equals(user.name)) {
           return false;
       }
       return true;
   }

   @Override
   public String toString() {
       final StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
       builder.append("Users [id=").append(id).append(", name=").append(name)
              .append(", roles=").append(roles).append("]");
       return builder.toString();
   }

public Long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public Timestamp getFx_High() {
    return fx_High;
}

public void setFx_High(Timestamp fx_High) {
    this.fx_High = fx_High;
}

public Timestamp getFx_Modification() {
    return fx_Modification;
}

public void setFx_Modification(Timestamp fx_Modification) {
    this.fx_Modification = fx_Modification;
}

public String getCertificate() {
    return certificate;
}

public void setCertificate(String certificate) {
    this.certificate = certificate;
}

public String getNif() {
    return nif;
}

public void setNif(String nif) {
    this.nif = nif;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}

public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}

public String getFirstname() {
    return firstname;
}

public void setFirstname(String firstname) {
    this.firstname = firstname;
}

public String getLastname() {
    return lastname;
}

public void setLastname(String lastname) {
    this.lastname = lastname;
}

public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}

public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}

public Long getState() {
    return state;
}

public void setState(Long state) {
    this.state = state;
}

public List<Privilege> getPrivileges() {
    return privileges;
}

public void setPrivileges(List<Privilege> privileges) {
    this.privileges = privileges;
}

public List<Role> getRoles() {
    return roles;
}

public void setRoles(List<Role> roles) {
    this.roles = roles;
}

public Long getPhone() {
    return phone;
}

public void setPhone(Long phone) {
    this.phone = phone;
}

public List<Sp> getSp_manager() {
    return sp_manager;
}

public void setSp_manager(List<Sp> sp_manager) {
    this.sp_manager = sp_manager;
}

public List<Sp> getSp_contact() {
    return sp_contact;
}

public void setSp_contact(List<Sp> sp_contact) {
    this.sp_contact = sp_contact;
}

public List<SpR> getSpr_manager() {
    return spr_manager;
}

public void setSpr_manager(List<SpR> spr_manager) {
    this.spr_manager = spr_manager;
}

public List<SpR> getSpr_contact() {
    return spr_contact;
}

public void setSpr_contact(List<SpR> spr_contact) {
    this.spr_contact = spr_contact;
}

public List<Solicitude> getSolicitude() {
    return solicitude;
}

public void setSolicitude(List<Solicitude> solicitude) {
    this.solicitude = solicitude;
}

public List<Solicitude> getSolicitude_res() {
    return solicitude_res;
}

public void setSolicitude_res(List<Solicitude> solicitude_res) {
    this.solicitude_res = solicitude_res;
}




}
```

Cuando añado, modifico o borro un usuario, **antes** de añadir las clases RevInfo y RevInfoListener, veo que me guarda bien en todas las tablas y la auditoria es correcta. Pero con estas dos clases me sale el siguiente error:

```
Caused by: javax.transaction.RollbackException: ARJUNA016053: Could not commit transaction.
        at com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.transaction.arjunacore.TransactionImple.commitAndDisassociate(TransactionImple.java:1212)
        at com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.transaction.arjunacore.BaseTransaction.commit(BaseTransaction.java:126)
        at com.arjuna.ats.jbossatx.BaseTransactionManagerDelegate.commit(BaseTransactionManagerDelegate.java:89)
        at org.jboss.tm.usertx.client.ServerVMClientUserTransaction.commit(ServerVMClientUserTransaction.java:178)
        at org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager.doCommit(JtaTransactionManager.java:1023)
        ... 144 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute statement
        at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.convert(SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.java:63)
        at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:42)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:109)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:95)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:207)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.NonBatchingBatch.addToBatch(NonBatchingBatch.java:45)
        at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2949)
        at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3449)
        at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityInsertAction.execute(EntityInsertAction.java:89)
        at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:582)
        at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:456)
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:337)
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:39)
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1282)
        at org.hibernate.envers.internal.synchronization.AuditProcess.doBeforeTransactionCompletion(AuditProcess.java:156)
        at org.hibernate.envers.internal.synchronization.AuditProcessManager$1.doBeforeTransactionCompletion(AuditProcessManager.java:46)
        at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue$BeforeTransactionCompletionProcessQueue.beforeTransactionCompletion(ActionQueue.java:928)
        at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.beforeTransactionCompletion(ActionQueue.java:503)
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:2340)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcCoordinatorImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(JdbcCoordinatorImpl.java:485)
        at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jta.internal.JtaTransactionCoordinatorImpl.beforeCompletion(JtaTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:316)
        at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jta.internal.synchronization.SynchronizationCallbackCoordinatorNonTrackingImpl.beforeCompletion(SynchronizationCallbackCoordinatorNonTrackingImpl.java:47)
        at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jta.internal.synchronization.RegisteredSynchronization.beforeCompletion(RegisteredSynchronization.java:37)
        at com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.resources.arjunacore.SynchronizationImple.beforeCompletion(SynchronizationImple.java:76)
        at com.arjuna.ats.arjuna.coordinator.TwoPhaseCoordinator.beforeCompletion(TwoPhaseCoordinator.java:371)
        at com.arjuna.ats.arjuna.coordinator.TwoPhaseCoordinator.end(TwoPhaseCoordinator.java:91)
        at com.arjuna.ats.arjuna.AtomicAction.commit(AtomicAction.java:162)
        at com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.transaction.arjunacore.TransactionImple.commitAndDisassociate(TransactionImple.java:1200)
        ... 148 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00904: "ID": invalid identifier

        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:450)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:399)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.processError(T4C8Oall.java:1017)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:655)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:249)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solucionado!!

El problema era que había creado la tabla REVINFO mal. Como podéis observar la Entidad Revinfo extiende de DefaultRevisionEntity y por tanto hereda las propiedades:

```
@Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @RevisionNumber
    private int id;

    @RevisionTimestamp
    private long timestamp;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
```

Yo en BBDD la tabla REVINFO la creé así:

```
 CREATE TABLE "DBADMIN"."REVINFO" 
   (    "REV" NUMBER(10,0) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "REVTSTMP" NUMBER(19,0), 
    "USER_NAME" VARCHAR2(200 BYTE), 
     PRIMARY KEY ("REV")
```

Si os dais cuenta la PK en lugar de llamarse ID es REV. El error decía "ID" Identifier invalid. Podéis hacer dos cosas para solucionar el problema

> 1. Cambiar el nombre de la columna REV por ID.
> 2. En la clase entidad crearos la propiedad REV (mismo nombre que en la tabla) y anotarla con @Id, y claro está quitar la herencia de
>      DefaultRevisionEntity.

Espero les sirva!!